# Booting problem from external hard drive

Tags: boot, grub2, external-hdd

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on an external hard drive using an Acer One netbook (Windows XP) and used the same external disk with another desktop PC (Windows XP).

Now it does not load Ubuntu. Instead I get an error message: 'hd0 missing' etc. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu, now a grub on text command prompt comes, like `grub>`.

I don't know what to do now. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Did you get into your BIOS and changed the booting order from internal hdd to external?